# iPhone image picker

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iphone application which needs to show a an array of images in a single view,user should also be able to view maximized view when selected.I am looking for a sample to do this .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController_Class.pdf)

Simply create one and add it to your view hierarchy and you get all that image picking behaviour for free.

Answer (score -1):

Well with the information I am getting from you, all you need to do is create a UIView and put images into it using:

```
UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake();
```

and then when the user taps or double taps on that view then make it animate:

```
[UIView beginAnimation:nil, context:nil];

//Change size here
```

[image1 setFrame:CGrectMake()];

```
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Ok I was not being mean, or at least not trying to be with what I said. So please undo the thumbs down, and if you are going to thumbs down then please tell me why, or I won't fix what I did wrong